# Subscribe to auto-login

Tags: 8, users

Looking for suggestions on how to subscribe to a login (I know I can use **hook_user_login**) when it's not "traditional". What I'm really looking for is to subscribe to anytime a user gets logged in via `$ drush uli`. Is there any way to tell HOW the user logged in?

Comment: I'd be tempted to add a route subscriber and hijack the route for /user/reset/{uid}/{timestamp}/{hash}/login, changing the callback to something under my own control. Then it's just a simple of matter of running your code in that callback, then calling the original controller method to finish up

Comment: Oh, great... I like that idea! Thank you. I suppose it wouldn't stop *every* method of logging in as a different user (you could use drush to change a users password), but I think that would accomplish 90% of what I want.